# The callable function called by std::call_once will hang if it tries to call std::call_once on the same std::once_flag

Tags: c++11

I ran into a bug caused by this behaviour:

```
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag onceFlag;

void get() {
    std::call_once(onceFlag, [](){ get(); });
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    get();
    return 0;
}
```

Another way of putting it would be:

```
#include <mutex>

std::once_flag onceFlag;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::call_once(onceFlag,
        [](){
            std::call_once(onceFlag,
                [](){}
            );
        }
    );

    return 0;
}
```

According to what I read here at cppreference (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) this is to be expected, as the first call to std::call_once hasn't finished executing:

> No invocation in the group returns before the above-mentioned
>   execution of the selected function is completed successfully, that is,
>   doesn't exit via an exception.

Why is the above a requirement? Couldn't the once_flag be set before the function is called, and reset if an exception is thrown?

Comment: Short answer: Because the committee decided it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the above a requirement? Couldn't the once_flag be set before
>   the function is called, and reset if an exception is thrown?

Well no. In your proposal `once_flag` will be set and then reseted in case of any failure. This might create race conditions. Consider such situation with 2 threads: `th1` and `th2`. Both are doing some task, which needs to be done exactly once. Threads rely on `once_flag` working as in your proposal. `th1` is inside function guarded with `once_flag`. `th2` is checking `once_flag` condition and stops execution, because from its pov task is finished. During task execution in `th1` exception is thrown, from `th1` pov it's fine, because some other worker will finish execution. Task is never finished because `th1` failed and `once_flag` is unset, but `th2` finished because `once_flag` was set, and it assumed that task is finished.

With current requirements, such inconsistency cannot happen.